# creating a Symfony project using composer

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to get Symfony in my Mac, so I installed symfony and composer in order to start developing, but when I create the project I have some problems:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton cost_management
Installing symfony/skeleton (v4.0.5)
  - Installing symfony/skeleton (v4.0.5): Loading from cache
Created project in cost_management
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 21 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/flex (v1.0.71): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.7.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/console (v4.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/routing (v4.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v4.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/yaml (v4.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/framework-bundle (v4.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v4.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v4.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/log (1.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/debug (v4.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/finder (v4.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/filesystem (v4.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/dependency-injection (v4.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/config (v4.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/cache (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/cache (v4.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/dotenv (v4.0.6): Loading from cache
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Symfony operations: 4 recipes (7c280e93acfad83db0b06dac8600cc2d)
  - Configuring symfony/flex (>=1.0): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring symfony/framework-bundle (>=3.3): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring symfony/console (>=3.3): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
  - Configuring symfony/routing (>=4.0): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
!!  
!!  Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "FileResource" from namespace "App".
!!  Did you forget a "use" statement for "Symfony\Component\Config\Resource\FileResource"? in /Users/gate11/Desktop/cost_management/src/Kernel.php:39
!!  Stack trace:
!!  #0 /Users/gate11/Desktop/cost_management/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Kernel/MicroKernelTrait.php(80): App\Kernel->configureContainer(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder), Object(Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\DelegatingLoader))
!!  #1 [internal function]: App\Kernel->Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\{closure}(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder))
!!  #2 /Users/gate11/Desktop/cost_management/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/ClosureLoader.php(38): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder))
!!  #3 /Users/gate11/Desktop/cost_management/vendor/symfony/config/Loader/DelegatingLoader.php(40): Symfony\Component\DependencyInj in /Users/gate11/Desktop/cost_management/src/Kernel.php on line 39
!!  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "FileResource" from namespace "App".
!!  Did you forget a "use" statement for "Symfony\Component\Config\Resource\FileResource"? in /Users/gate11/Desktop/cost_management/src/Kernel.php:39
!!  Stack trace:
!!  #0 /Users/gate11/Desktop/cost_management/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Kernel/MicroKernelTrait.php(80): App\Kernel->configureContainer(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder), Object(Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\DelegatingLoader))
!!  #1 [internal function]: App\Kernel->Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\{closure}(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder))
!!  #2 /Users/gate11/Desktop/cost_management/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/ClosureLoader.php(38): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder))
!!  #3 /Users/gate11/Desktop/cost_management/vendor/symfony/config/Loader/DelegatingLoader.php(40): Symfony\Component\DependencyInj in /Users/gate11/Desktop/cost_management/src/Kernel.php on line 39
!!
```

I tried many ways to install it, I saw the commands in their website, so I did it but still having some problems installing it.
If someone knows what's wrong with it, or if I need something else, I'm hoping for your help.
Thanks.

Comment: Which PHP version are you using?! If you're not using PHP 7.1, then you can't use Symfony 4 yet, nor can you use the new skeleton... Install the [Symfony instaler](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup.html) and use it to make a new project with the command `symfony new my_project 3.4`

Comment: There was a bug checked in a few hours ago. https://github.com/symfony/recipes/pull/380 It is being worked on.  Monitor the issue then try again.

Comment: I'm using php 7.1.14n I think there was a bug because I don't get the problem here.

Comment: @Preciel I can't use symfony without using composer
[RuntimeException]                                                           
  The Symfony Installer is not compatible with Symfony 4.x or newer versions.  
  Run this other command to install Symfony using Composer instead:            
  composer create-project symfony/skeleton cost

Comment: In case anybody is wondering, the issue has been solved and create-project is now working again.

Answer (score 2):

Please replace `composer create-project symfony/skeleton cost_management` with `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton cost_management`

```
            **OR**
```

You could install and setup Symfony4 application on Ubuntu with PHP7.2 by these steps execute through temminal:

1. `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton cost_management`
2. `cd cost_management`
3. `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public`
4. `ctrl + c` to exit server run `composer install`
5. `sudo chmod 777 -R var/cache/ var/log/`
6. now again `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public`
7. Now you can check on your browser by this `http://localhost:8000/` or directly you can access without server run by `http://localhost/project_directory/public/index.php`

`Note:-` 
 1. By default symfony 4 is set to dev environment, but you could set
    your environment by setting `$_SERVER['APP_ENV']`
 2. If it's working proper then you will see a 404 error message and profiler in bottom because it's by default set to `dev` mode.
 3. To see something you need to create your first controller by following documents [Symfony 4 create your first page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just add this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Config\Resource\FileResource;
```

to the top of your  src/Kernel.php, it was missed for some reason.

After that, you can continue with `composer install`

Comment: I added it, the project was created, but when I start the http://127.0.0.1:8000, I have this errors: 
Notice: Undefined index: APP_DEBUG in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cost_management/public/index.php on line 19
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cost_management/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php on line 144